# Get Current Location 0 in marshmallow where below 23 API its give exact current Location using fused Location

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-6.0-marshmallow

*I got current Location in Below 23 devices but getting (0.0,0.0) latitude and Longitude in 23 emulator device.*

**EDIT**
Currently I am using Fused Location Provider for get Current Location

```
public class ContactUsFragment extends Fragment implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("TAG", "OnCreate Called");
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    buildGoogleApiClient();


}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_us, container, false);

    Log.i("TAG", "OnCreateView Called");
    setComponants(view);  // **** Method For Set Componants Of Layout
```

*This is Map Image on click of it I want to get current Location and  pass it to Native Google Map app of device for navigate to target Location*

```
 mapImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("TAG", "On ImageView Click");


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

                if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getActivity())) {

                    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                        navigateToGoogleMap();
                    } else {
                        showSettingsAlert();
                    }
                } else {
                    requestPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE, getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getActivity());
                }
            } else {

                if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    navigateToGoogleMap();
                } else {
                    showSettingsAlert();
                }

            }


        }


    });
    return view;
}
```

*Below is code for get  Current Location*

```
private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Log.i("TAG", "Building GoogleApiClient");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    createLocationRequest();
}

private void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    //**************************
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
    //**************************

}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    Location mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    // Note that this can be NULL if last location isn't already known.
    if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
        // Print current location if not null
        Log.d("DEBUG", "current location: " + mCurrentLocation.toString());
        currentlatitude = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
        currentlongitude = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
    }
    // Begin polling for new location updates.
    startLocationUpdates();
}

private void startLocationUpdates() {

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
            mLocationRequest, this);
}

private void stopLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    if (i == CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Disconnected. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (i == CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Network lost. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    String msg = "Updated Location: " +
            Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
            Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    currentlatitude = location.getLatitude();
    currentlongitude = location.getLongitude();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

*This code is Working Properly when I use in below API23 devices but when I try on marshmallow Device it give current Location 0.0,0.0 *

*Below is my Manifest file*

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@layout/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DoctorsDetailsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".ServiceActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? What does your code look like and what have you tried so far? Please read the basics on [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update yours. I'm voting to close for now for being unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @VishalHalani did you tried what I wrote in my answer below??

Comment: @Abhishek I tried it but still its give 0 latLng.

Comment: @VishalHalani post your manifest file with code

Comment: @Abhishek I have post my manifest file code.

Comment: @VishalHalani  <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> add these also and then try again

Comment: @Abhishek still not working.same issue.

Comment: @VishalHalani ok now I am writing my code under do try that

Comment: @Abhishek Dear Same Issue .get 0.0 lattitude and 0.0 longitude I was tried before this code from hive. but still same getting problem

Comment: @VishalHalani .. I have also stucked in the same problem..Plz help me to short out from these problem..thanks

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha dear what you get error. debug your code and put breakpoint onconnectionfailed method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I got exact problem after some debugging and searching**

**GoogleAPIclient onConnected() not called so it called onConnectionFailed() method**

**In that Method I found error code it was 2 it mean REQUIRED PLAY SERVICE UPDATE**

**so I change play service in gradle file same as Device Playservice  version so I get Current Location**

I post Some code Here:

```
private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
 Log.i("TAG", "Building GoogleApiClient");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    createLocationRequest();}

private void createLocationRequest() {
    Log.i("TAG", "CreateLocationRequest");
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000;
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 10000;
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    //**************************
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
    //**************************

}

private void startLocationUpdates() {

    Log.i("TAG", "StartLocationUpdates");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                    mLocationRequest, this);

        }
    } else {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}

private void stopLocationUpdates() {
    Log.i("TAG", "StopLocationUpdates");
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);

}
 @Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i("TAG", "onConnectionSuspended");
    if (i == CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Disconnected. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (i == CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Network lost. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i("TAG", "OnLocationChanged");
    Log.i("TAG", "Current Location==>" + location);
    currentlatitude = location.getLatitude();
    currentlongitude = location.getLongitude();
}


    @Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), connectionResult.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("TAG", "Location services connection failed with code==>" + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        Log.e("TAG", "Location services connection failed Because of==> " + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Location mCurrentLocation;

    Log.i("TAG", "OnConnected");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

            // Note that this can be NULL if last location isn't already known.
            if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
                // Print current location if not null
                Log.d("DEBUG", "current location: " + mCurrentLocation.toString());
                currentlatitude = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
                currentlongitude = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
            } else {
                startLocationUpdates();
            }


        }
    } else {
        mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        // Note that this can be NULL if last location isn't already known.
        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            // Print current location if not null
            Log.d("DEBUG", "current location: " + mCurrentLocation.toString());
            currentlatitude = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
            currentlongitude = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
        }
        // Begin polling for new location updates.
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}
```

For more Refer Official Docs https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Hello there! can you please let me know weather this will work in case we do not have internet connection .. ??

Answer (score 10):

Use below code. Hope this is useful.

Make sure you run this code into real device only.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener
{
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
        else
        {
            if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            {
                showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
            }
        }

        mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GPS is disabled in your device. Would you like to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {
                        Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);

                        mapFrag.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);
                    }
                });
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
            {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mGoogleMap=googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
    {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
    {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null)
        {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

    public boolean checkLocationPermission()
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
            {
                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            else
            {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            {
                showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
    {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION:
            {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {

                        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
                        {
                            showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
                        }

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null)
                        {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sneha.mymapdemo">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR API KEY"/>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

It maybe help you to known that.

I found that the Network provider not working in some android devices When you disable GPS because they're prevent access location data if GPS not enabled.

I've tried that on many devices
 1. lenove k6 note ([screen shot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Edo.jpg) , [screen shot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Edo.jpg))
 2. Xiomai mi 9t [screen shot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93HeE.jpg)
 3. Google Pixel 1 & Pixel 2

so some devices need GPS enabled to access location from LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER and you can't get location data without enable GPS