# GoogleService failed to initialize because of missing dependency in gradle.

Tags: android, google-play-services

Everything was working perfect in my project but know I get this message.

```
 GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource:   
 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes 
  are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle    
  plugin
```

So I should add the google-service in my gradle file.

```
  buildscript {
        repositories {
        jcenter()
   }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
  }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
  }
}

   task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and these are  my dependencies.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Basically I use the GoogleApiClient object to obtain my current location. I have nothing to do with Maps or GCM.

Any ideas how to fix this? I looked around here, but still there are problems.

Thanks.

Comment: try this answer on stack overflow.... http://stackoverflow.com/a/34436291/3678308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to generate and configure file from [Developer.Google](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cntapp=Default%20Demo%20App&cntpkg=com.google.samples.quickstart.signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fstart%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20with%20Try%20Sign-In)
  `google-services.json` file from this site.
- Open the Android Studio Terminal pane:
  [image]

  Alternativiely you can just press `ALT + F12`

> Type this line in `Terminal`

- MAC/LINUX:

> `mv path-to-download/Downloads/google-services.json app/`

- WINDOWS

> `move path-to-download/Downloads/google-services.json app/`

1) Add the dependency to your project-level build.gradle:

```
 compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

2) Add the plugin to your app-level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

> note: below `dependencies{ ....... }` blog

- Then use Play service dependencies in app level

`dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'

}`

Comment: I fixed the error few days ago but your answer is really good and detailed. :)