# Getting CurrentLocation 0 using fused location when google play service is different in app and device

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-fusedlocation

I am trying to get Current location using Fusedlocationservice.

In my gradle file i have put  below playservice version

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

Now if in device have latest version of google playservice then its work well. it give proper location.

But if device have lower version then its not give current location.

Its also give warning in logcat like below:

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9452000 but found 6184738
```

So its mandatory to have latest version of playservice in device  to get current location..?

If  yes then i need alternet solution for this. because every user not able to update service in device so.

my code you can see here .[Get Current Location 0 in marshmallow where below 23 API its give exact current Location using fused Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305377/get-current-location-0-in-marshmallow-where-below-23-api-its-give-exact-current/34436291)

Any Help will highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put **google play service** version to **7.3** in gradle instead of latest version.

Because every user not have latest version of play service so if you put latest version of play service in  application it always take null location if  device have lower version play service. else user have to update play service to match application play service version.

So I have put lower version of playservice in app. build so its supports in each device which have equal or higher version.

got reference from doc. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#ensure_devices_have_the_google_play_services_apk

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know FusedLocation was added in Play Service 7.0 and the one you posted is **6184738** is 6.1 i guess, you can check [here all the release changelog](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases), so it should work on devices with play services 7.0 or higher

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this document: [Ensure Devices Have the Google Play services APK](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#ensure_devices_have_the_google_play_services_apk)

> As described in the [**Google Play services overview**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview.html), Google Play delivers service updates for users on Android 2.3 and higher through the Google Play Store app. However, updates might not reach all users immediately, so your app should verify the version available before attempting to perform API transactio
>
> You are strongly encouraged to use the [**`GoogleApiClient`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html) class to access Google Play services features. This approach allows you to attach an [**`OnConnectionFailedListener`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener.html) object to your client. To detect if the device has the appropriate version of the Google Play services APK, implement the [**`onConnectionFailed()`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener.html#onConnectionFailed(com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult)) callback method. If the connection fails due to a missing or out-of-date version of the Google Play APK, the callback receives an error code such as [**`SERVICE_MISSING`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SERVICE_MISSING), [**`SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED), or [**`SERVICE_DISABLED`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SERVICE_DISABLED). To learn more about how to build your client and handle such connection errors, see [**Accessing Google APIs**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client.html).
>
> Another approach is to use the [**`isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)) method. You might call this method in the [**`onResume()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) method of the main activity. If the result code is [**`SUCCESS`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SUCCESS), then the Google Play services APK is up-to-date and you can continue to make a connection. If, however, the result code is [**`SERVICE_MISSING`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SERVICE_MISSING), [**`SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED), or [**`SERVICE_DISABLED`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SERVICE_DISABLED), **then the user needs to install an update**. In this case, call the [**`getErrorDialog()`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#getErrorDialog(int,%20android.app.Activity,%20int)) method and pass it the result error code. The method returns a [**`Dialog`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) you should show, **which provides an appropriate message about the error and provides an action that takes the user to Google Play Store to install the update**.

**Note**: Because it is hard to anticipate the state of each device, you must always check for a compatible Google Play services APK before you access Google Play services features.

Hope it helps!