# OnLocationChanged Method is not called in LeEco phones

Tags: android, on-location-changed

I am using **GoogleApiClient** to get the location and that is working fine for some devices like Redmi, Honor, Samsung, Moto etc. but when I am using LeEco devices my **onLocationChanged** method does not call. is there anything which I have to add in my code for **LeEco** devices?

Comment: please check permission in device

Comment: which permissions??

Comment: location permission

Comment: i have already given location permission.

Comment: permission in device or manifest

Comment: already given in manifest too and for marshmallow and higher devices, i have given permission at run time. Actually, my same code is working in other devices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150159/discussion-between-naveen-tamrakar-and-shaifali-pundir).

Comment: @ShaifaliPundir see this issue i think your device playservice  version and app play service is different  check  it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305377/get-current-location-0-in-marshmallow-where-below-23-api-its-give-exact-current